# Four newest images 2x2 with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to reuse some PHP that I found on here, but I don't have much experience with PHP and became stuck.

When uploading images from a camera and I'd like to be able to display the 4 newest images as large as possible while fitting on a screen without scrolling.  2 wide, 2 high: dividing the full screen resolution into 4 quadrants.  The initial PHP prints them down in a column (by adding a break after each image in the loop), and I now have them printing horizontally as well. However, they are too small to reasonably view from a distance.  I'm not sure how to print two, create a line break, and then print the last two.  Or if there is a way to do it with a table and have one image in each `td`

Here's where I am right now:

```
<?php

$images = glob('images/*.{jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE); //formats to look for

$num_of_files = 4; //number of images to display

foreach($images as $image)
{
     $num_of_files--;

     if($num_of_files > -1) 
       echo "<img src="."'".$image."'".">"; 
     else
       break;
}
?>
```

I'm using some CSS to add z-index, but this is the basic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to print 2 and then a line break and then 2 you could use

```
  foreach($images as $image) {
     $num_of_files--;

     if($num_of_files > -1){
       echo '<img src="' . $image . '" id="png' . $num_of_files . '" width="50%">';
       if($num_of_files % 2 == 0)
         echo "<br />";
     }
     else
       break; 
  }
```

And see this SO post about sorting the glob
[glob() - sort by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124958/glob-sort-by-date)

Comment: That is the ticket!  Fantastic and much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add some css;

```
img {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to clean up your code and make it a touch more generic:

```
<?php

$images = glob('images/*.{jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE); //formats to look for
$images_printed = 0;
$images_per_row = 2;

foreach($images as $image) {
   echo "<img src="."'".$image."'".">";
   $images_printed++;
   if ($images_printed % $images_per_row == 0) {
      echo "<br/>";
   }
}
```

Note that leaving off `?>` at the end of your code file will prevent accidental inclusion of whitespace characters that can otherwise throw off formatting.