# sort file by last modified php glob

Tags: php, glob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [glob() - sort by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124958/glob-sort-by-date)

I want to sort files based on uploaded date by using php glob. How do I sort it by showing the latest 'modified'/uploaded pic 1st on the list?

```
<?php
$files = glob("uploaded_files/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) { 
    $num = $files[$i];
    asort($files);
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" style="height:180px; width:180px; border:2px solid black; margin:20px 0px 10px  10px; *margin:10px 0px 10px 20px;" />'."&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: just try to work around filemtime($files[$i]) also..

Comment: see here:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124958/glob-sort-by-date

Answer (score 6):

```
$files = glob("uploaded_files/*.*");
usort($files, function ($a, $b) {
   return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a);
});
```

Comment: @ShazeryNasir "doesn't work" is a very broad description of a problem

Comment: sorry. by doesnt work i mean that the page doesnt show. it crash.

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: the php version is 5.3.20

Comment: This works for me on PHP 5.4.6 .. I'd be surprised if it wasn't working on PHP 5.3 though.  Have you tried running it from the command line?

Comment: is the 'for' action causing the problem? mind seeing my whole code?

Comment: My code doesn't use `for`.  Are you using your code or my code?

Comment: im adding your code to my code. since i need to also style the images that is being shown on the page

Comment: Sorry, don't do that.  My code is supposed to do what you want to do by itself.  Just use my code and then `var_dump($files)` to see if it's working; *then* you can work on markup

Comment: when i use var_dump. it lists the array of files. it doesnt display the images inside the folder

Comment: it displays the array of files available inside the folder. just text

Comment: Okay great, so it's working.  *After* my code, do `foreach ($files as $file) { echo "<img src='$file'>"; }`

Comment: thanks a lot Explosion Pills (im guessing its not your real name ;p) for your help. it works. :)