# list of file names as dates, arrange in date order?

Tags: php, jquery, file, date

I have a bunch of files on my server with file names from 'april2009' to 'march2013', a file for every month in between (plus a new file for every month from now onwards will be added).

I tried arranging in order by using 'filemtime', but this gave a random order as they appear to have been modified all over the place.

How can I sort through the file names and arrange in order, starting at most recent first?

(getting the file names with php, but can use jquery or a mix for this purpose)

thanks

Comment: The obvious solution is: Change the filenames to be yyyy-mm-dd instead of your current format and then sort by name. But I guess that's out of the question?

Comment: Check the accepted answer here. Is just what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124958/glob-sort-by-date

Comment: it is yes, the filenames are set like this as they are being used in multiple other places which code would need to be changed for as well

Comment: @Ateszki Please read the question properly. The OP clearly states that sorting by modification time doesn't work.

Comment: @Till Helge Helwig sorry, you are right! I missed the part that the files have modified after creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) is *amazing* for date conversion.

Once you have retrieve your file list, you can do:

```
$date = strtotime('april2003');
```

Which will give you: `1049155200`. Which means:

> 1/4/2003 à 2:00:00

Once you have your timestamp, you can do what ever you want to sort it.

Here is a POC:

```
$dirs = array();
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/dir')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && is_dir($entry)) {
            $dirs[strtotime(substr($entry, 0, -5))] = $entry;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

krsort($dirs);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Im struggling with something though: the directory files have a .html extension, which i think is messing up the strtotime. i was getting around this using 'substr($file, 0 , -5);', but in unsure how to implement this into the above code?

Answer (score 0):

To put it mildly, this should have been thought about before coming up with the file namning convention. As pointed out in the comments, the only sensible naming convention is a sortable one yyyy-mm or yyyy-mm-dd.

In this case your only option is to:

1. Load the list of file names
2. While loading them, convert the names to a sortable form (so you would transform april2003 to 200304)
3. As you load them place them in an array of the form $img[$sortablefilename] = $real file name (e.g. $img['200304'] = 'april2003';)
4. Use ksort to sort the resulting array
5. Read through the sorted array using the real file names to display the images