# PHP Sorting files by Date/time and file size

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, filesize

I am working on modifying a simple website.  This website has a page that shows a clients files available for download(if applicable).  At the moment these files are just in random order with no specific details.  I would like to be able to have them in decending order based on time stamp that they were made available.  Also including their file size.  This is using php to show the files, do I need to have the directory already sorted before displaying them? if so would that be a separate script and when would it be run? Or can I sort them as they are displayed in the follwoing code?

```
<div id="f2">
<h3>Files Available for Download</h3>
<p>
<?php
// list contents of user directory
if (file_exists($USER_DIRECTORY)) {
    if ($handle = opendir($USER_DIRECTORY)) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                echo "<a href='download_file.php?filename=".urlencode($entry)."'>".$entry."</a><br/>";
            }
        }
    closedir($handle);
    }
}

?>
</p>

</div>
```

Very new to php, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: [**Check out this answer on SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/125047/1415724) based on the [**glob( ) function**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). May help to shed a bit of light on the subject. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here's a snippet which could be of help.

It makes an `href` out of each file or file extension specified. Modify to suit.

- It is presently coded to use the `asort()` function. [Consult the PHP manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

It can easily be changed to `usort()`. [Consult the PHP manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

See also the `arsort()` function. [Consult the PHP manual.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)

The filesize is also included, yet it is not formatted as bytes, kb etc. There are functions out there that will format it to suit. **Google** "filesize format php". [**This link has that information.**](http://codebyte.dev7studios.com/post/1590919646/php-format-filesize)

```
<?php

// You can use the desired folder to check and comment the others.
// foreach (glob("../downloads/*") as $path) { // lists all files in sub-folder called "downloads"
foreach (glob("test/*") as $path) { // lists all files in folder called "test"
//foreach (glob("*.php") as $path) { // lists all files with .php extension in current folder
    $docs[$path] = filectime($path);
} asort($docs); // sort by value, preserving keys

foreach ($docs as $path => $timestamp) {
    print date("d M. Y: ", $timestamp);
    print '<a href="'. $path .'">'. basename($path) .'</a>' . " Size: " . filesize($path) .'<br />';
}
?>
```

Pulled from that link http://codebyte.dev7studios.com/post/1590919646/php-format-filesize, should it ever cease to exist:

```
function filesize_format($size, $sizes = array('Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'))
{
    if ($size == 0) return('n/a');
    return (round($size/pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2) . ' ' . $sizes[$i]);
}
```