# Ordering results by most recently added

Tags: php, image

Im using this code to list all the images in a folder on the page, the class "results" holds the 4 images per paginated page. I can only get them to list in alphabetical order, how can I get them by most recently added?

```
<?php                           
    $files = glob("upload_image/*.*");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i += 4) {
        $colCnt++;
        if ($colCnt == 1) {
            $num = $files[$i];
        }

        echo '<div class="result"><img src="' . $files[$i] . 
                             '" /><img src="' . $files[$i + 1] . 
                             '" /><img src="' . $files[$i + 2] . 
                             '" /><img src="' . $files[$i + 3].'" /> ';
        echo'</div>';

        if ($colCnt == 1) {      
            $colCnt = 0;
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: How do you know the add time? Figure that one out and sorting will be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **[filemtime](https://www.php.net/filemtime)** over the results will get you all their times and then you can simply sort that array based upon that time.

```
<?php
 $files = glob("upload_image/*.*");
 usort($files, create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);'));
?>
```

[**Credit**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/125047/1570534)