# Order results of glob by modified date

Tags: php, glob

I am running glob against a folder holding revisions, I would like it to order them ideally by modify date.  If I have to I can work with alphabetically in Descending order.

Do I just go with filename

```
$files = arsort(glob("*.rev"));
```

or is there a better way that uses modify date?

Comment: Use your glob list with [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map), [**`filemtime`**](http://php.net/filemtime), [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine), [`krsort`](http://php.net/krsort).

Comment: I think I found what you're looking for here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124958/glob-sort-by-date

Comment: I think you may be right, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124958/glob-sort-by-date is the better of the two duplicates.