# How to sort pictures from newest to oldest?

Tags: image, sorting, directory

I have this script. It works by taking all the pictures in a folder, and make a webpage of it. Oldest picture on top, and newer pictures down the page.

How can I revert the way the pictures are displayed? I want the newest on top.

```
<?php
$folder = 'ute/grabs/';
$filetype = '*.*';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
$count = count($files);
echo '<table>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
echo '<tr><td>';
echo '<a name="'.$i.'" href="#'.$i.'"><img src="'.$files[$i].'" /></a>';
echo substr($files[$i],strlen($folder),strpos($files[$i], '.')-strlen($folder));
echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this after glob.

```
usort($files, create_function('$b,$a', 'return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);'));
```

See: [glob() - sort by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124958/glob-sort-by-date)

Note: I have changed the first argument of the "create_function" to reverse the order.

Comment: That was great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Icarus3
That worked great.

This was the final solution:

```
<?php
$folder = 'webcam/webcam/ute/grabs/';
$filetype = '*.jpg';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
usort($files, create_function('$b,$a', 'return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);'));
$count = count($files);
echo '<table>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
echo '<tr><td>';
echo '<a name="'.$i.'" href="#'.$i.'"><img src="'.$files[$i].'" /></a><br>';
echo substr($files[$i],strlen($folder),strpos($files[$i], '.')-strlen($folder));
echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>'; 
?>
```